# Dynamically change font of a label in windows forms

Tags: c#, file, io, windows-forms-designer

I saved the font of a label in a file named file.txt and every time the program runs, i read the file.txt and the font. actually i want to change label's font by coding.
saving font :

```
            string[] t = new string[2];
            t[0] = label1.Font.Name.ToString();
            t[1] = label1.Font.Size.ToString();

            File.WriteAllLines(@"file.txt", t);
```

reading font :

```
                label1.Font = new Font(t[0], (float)(int.Parse(t[1])));
```

but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things is important ,check that the font is installed on system and check that the name of the font is written correctly.

[image]